# after clicking on toggle ,how to change the background color of navbar in mobile mode?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the color of the list that appears after clicking on toggle in mobile mode(responsive).Currently it is transparent.
Which div should I target to change the dropdown that appears after clicking on toggle to change the background-color of the dropdown list.
Please help me I am new to bootstrap.
If you need to check my output let me know.

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  background: #E0FFFF;
  border: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: black;
  background: #13B1CD;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  background: #13B1CD;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #13B1CD;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu> li> a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: white;
  color:#13B1CD;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color:white;
  /* I have just used it to change the  regular toggle color */
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar :hover { /*Not working */
  background-color:white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu> li> a:hover {   /* This i haved used to change the hover of dropdown menu*/
  background:white;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation" style="background-color:white;border:none;color:black;height:90px;">
    <div class="container" style="font-family:Century Gothic, sans-serif; margin-top:18px;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button style="background-color:#13B1CD" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <!-- data-target is used to target line 43 navbar-->
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <!--Toogle navigation  cannot be seen due to sr-only,it is only used tell users that this part is toggle navigation,only programmers it is usable-->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <!-- Writing this span tag three times to produce three lines in toggle button that is used in small screen-->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand"> <img src="https://sampletrunk.com/assets2/img/Slicing/Logo.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="color:black;">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                         aria-hidden="true"> </span><b> Home</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutus"><b>About Us</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#products"><b>Products</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#services"><b>Services</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#awards"><b>Awards</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contacts"><b>Contacts</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#careers"><b>Careers</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: please share your full code. or website link.

Comment: you can look this answer to write different css for different devices https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605310/5383669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set background in `.navbar-nav` in media query

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  background: #E0FFFF;
  border: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: black;
  background: #13B1CD;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  background: #13B1CD;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #13B1CD;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu> li> a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: white;
  color:#13B1CD;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color:white;
  /* I have just used it to change the  regular toggle color */
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar :hover { /*Not working */
  background-color:white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu> li> a:hover {   /* This i haved used to change the hover of dropdown menu*/
  background:white;
  color:white;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    background: #333;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation" style="background-color:white;border:none;color:black;height:90px;">
    <div class="container" style="font-family:Century Gothic, sans-serif; margin-top:18px;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button style="background-color:#13B1CD" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <!-- data-target is used to target line 43 navbar-->
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <!--Toogle navigation  cannot be seen due to sr-only,it is only used tell users that this part is toggle navigation,only programmers it is usable-->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <!-- Writing this span tag three times to produce three lines in toggle button that is used in small screen-->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand"> <img src="https://sampletrunk.com/assets2/img/Slicing/Logo.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="color:black;">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                         aria-hidden="true"> </span><b> Home</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutus"><b>About Us</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#products"><b>Products</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#services"><b>Services</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#awards"><b>Awards</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contacts"><b>Contacts</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#careers"><b>Careers</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can just add this `css` code to make a colored background to your list:

```
  #navbar > ul {
    background-color:#eee; /*choose the color code you prefer, just an example*/
  }
```

Or did I miss / misunderstood anything?

Answer (score 0):

you on only need to apply your changes on css class

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse {
    background-color: whatever-you-need;
    color: here-a-color;
}
```

or apply a media query if you only need to apply your changes on mobile views.

e.g

```
@media(max-width: your-width) {
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse {
       background-color: #your-color;
       color: #your-color;
    }
  }
```